# how to get a value from a json key value pair in linux shell scripting

Tags: json, linux, bash, shell, sh

hi i am writings a small shell script. there i use curl command to call to api. what it return is a status of a scan.

```
{"status":"14"}
```

i want to get this status and check if it is less than 100; this is what i have done so far

```
    a=0

    while [ $a -lt 100 ]
    do

        curlout=$(curl "http://localhost:9090/JSON/spider/view/status/?zapapiformat=JSON&scanId=0");
        echo "$curlout";
       a=`expr $a + 1`
    done
```

what i want to do is assign that status to $a; how to get read this json to get the value in shell script

Comment: `sed -r '/status/s/^.*"([0-9]+).*$/\1/' <<< "$curlout"` worked for you?

Comment: `echo '{"status":"14"}' | tr -cd '0-9\n'`?

Comment: post the output of `curl "http://localhost:9090/JSON/spider/view/status/?zapapiformat=JSON&scanId=0"`. And what is the purpose of incrementing the value of `status` if it's always static?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to work with JSON, you should obtain `jq`:

```
$ echo '{"status": "14"}' | jq '.status|tonumber'
14
```

or, less rigorously:

```
$ echo '{"status": "14"}' | jq -r '.status'
14
```

Comment: How to set it to a variable

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure about the format of the curl output, then it's very simple.

```
echo "$curlout" | tr -cd '[:digit:]'
```

From [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) of `tr`,

```
   -c, -C, --complement
          use the complement of SET1

   -d, --delete
          delete characters in SET1, do not translate

   [:digit:]
          all digits
```

So this command removes all characters other than digits.